# How can i access my json Datetime value from my react component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I tried to access it returned Nothing because its not a date format.
Its seems i need to convert it to date format but i have no idea how ? can i get some opinions on how i can solve this?

My Json Object

```
{
  "rent": 0,
  "rentalPeriodStart": "2021-06-24T19:02:38.285Z",
  "rentalPeriodEnd": "2021-06-24T19:02:38.285Z"
}
```

How i called it

```
  <p>
   Valid from : {contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodStart}
  </p>
  <p>Until: {contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodEnd} </p>
```

Comment: You can try `new Date("2021-06-24T19:02:38.285Z")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this function for formatting and use it:

```
const getFormattedDate = (dateStr: string) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  return date.toLocaleDateString();
}

<p>
   Valid from : {getFormattedDate(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodStart)}
</p>
<p>Until: {getFormattedDate(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodEnd)} </p>
```

Here are few more examples for you to try:

```js
const obj = {
  rent: 0,
  rentalPeriodStart: "2021-06-24T19:02:38.285Z",
  rentalPeriodEnd: "2021-06-24T19:02:38.285Z"
}

// Version 1
const getFormattedDate1 = (dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  return date.toLocaleDateString();
}

// Version 2
const getFormattedDate2 = (dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  return date.toLocaleString();
}

console.log("Format 1 --->", getFormattedDate1(obj.rentalPeriodStart));
console.log("Format 2 --->", getFormattedDate2(obj.rentalPeriodStart));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
 <p>
   Valid from : {`${new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodStart).getDate()}/${new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodStart).getMonth() +1}/${new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodStart).getFullYear()}`}
  </p>
  <p>Until: {`${new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodEnd).getDate()}/${new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodEnd).getMonth() +1}/${new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodEnd).getFullYear()}`} </p>
```

This is just using template string to return a dd/mm/yyyy format for your date.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert it into date, then you can simple do this inside your code:

```
   <p>
   Valid from : {new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodStart)}
   </p>
   <p>Until: {new Date(contract.rentalObject.rentalPeriodEnd)} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse with new Date() as this: `new Date(data.rentalPeriodStart).toDateString()`

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-http-srkyh